# Windows: Getting /prefetch:1 while passing args to the electron app's main process from cmd using start command

Tags: windows, command-line, electron, command-line-arguments, command-prompt

I'm in Windows 10 & I'm trying to open an app using `start` command which goes like:

`start "C:\Program Files\MyElectronApp\MyElectronApp.exe"` which opens the app as expected.

I also want to pass some arguments after the above-mentioned command such as:

`start "C:\Program Files\MyElectronApp\MyElectronApp.exe" --UUID=762835745634 --org_token=r8347t89457`

When I write this command, I get `UUID` as `/prefetch:1` despite passing any thing, I tried adding double quotes "", but same issue. However, I manage to get `org_token` as expected. as shown in the screenshot.

What could be causing this issue?[image: issue screenshot cmd attached]

**What I tried to address the issue?**

I tried to add double quotes for the value of UUID, then I tried to use powershell and git bash for the same thinking it could solve the issue. Then, I checked the prefetch folder only to find it's empty. Then, I changed the order of args, but nothing happened.

Answer (score 0):

**Here's how I solved it:**

The args should NOT be in UPPERCASE, in this case it's `UUID`, I changed it to small case `uuid`. For windows uppercase args are reserved or fixed for some DOS-level stuff.

Just change:

`start "C:\Program Files\MyElectronApp\MyElectronApp.exe" --UUID=762835745634 --org_token=r8347t89457`

to

`start "C:\Program Files\MyElectronApp\MyElectronApp.exe" --uuid=762835745634 --org_token=r8347t89457`

The exact reason for this is not clear as I couldn't find one. Will certainly update this once I get to know the same.